# How to search specific prefix and add new character to its every number?

Tags: linux, perl, awk, sed

I have this output in a test.txt

```
S1:158,525 S6:17,322,534,536,546,598 S2:317,478,484,573 S7:313,513 S3:89,107,618,625,632 S8:305,327,336,408,592 S4:30,567,568,585,588 S5:333,617,619 S10:41,202,496,603
```

How to make it be like this?:

```
S1:158c1;525c1 S6:17c6;322c6;534c6;536c6;546c6;598c6 S2:317c2;478c2;484c2;573c2 S7:313c7;513c7 S3:89c3;107c3;618c3;625c3;632c3 S8:305c8;327c8;336c8;408c8;592c8 S4:30c4;567c4;568c4;585c4;588c4 S5:333c5;617c5;619c5 S10:41c10;202c10;496c10;603c10
```

I want every S{n} that have numbers to output c{n},


E.g:

S1:123,1234 become S1:123c1;1234c1


Please help me..


Thanks,

Am

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please use CODE TAGS by using {} button for your samples in your post.

Comment: cat test.txt | awk '/S1:/{gsub(",","c1;",$0); print; next}{print $0}' it will output S1:158c1;525 S6:17c1;322c1;534c1;536c1;546c1;598 S2:317c1;478c1;484c1;573 S7:313c1;513 S3:89c1;107c1;618c1;625c1;632 S8:305c1;327c1;336c1;408c1;592 S4:30c1;567c1;568c1;585c1;588 S5:333c1;617c1;619 S10:41c1;202c1;496c1;603

Comment: Please don't just simply minus point for this question, its disrespect. If I didn't respond for awhile then it means I'm busy with my work.

Comment: Very sorry for not replying. Anyway thanks for the help guys, I have found my own solution.

Comment: @Amz your awk solution is missing `c10` at the very end behind `603`, isn't it? (and c*n* at every last number)

Comment: @Amz if you've found a solution, please consider posting it as a reply ;)

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: my solution is very long and inefficient, so I'm using solution from Mr. Kjetil S. instead. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works:

```
perl -pe's{S(\d+):(\S+)}{my$n=$1;"S$n:".$2=~s/\d+/$&c$n/gr=~s/,/;/gr}ge' test.txt
```

There are three regexp search-replaces involved here:

- The outer one `s{...}{...}ge` changes every `Sn:somethingnotspace`
- The first inner one (`s/\d+/$&c$n/gr`) adds `c$n` to every integer number. $& is the match and $n is obtaned from $1 in the outer search-replace.
- The second inner one (`s/,/;/gr`) chages all commas into semicolons.

The /e regexp modifier (or `}ge` here) have a code block instead of a string for the replacement. Executes that code and uses the last statement of it as the replacement.

The /r modifier (as in /gr here) returns the regexp-replaced string (without changing the variable, but that's not important here) instead of returning the number of changes it made (the default).

The three /g modifiers search-replaces every match, not just the first.

Need Perl version 5.14 or higher for the `/r` modifier to work (run `perl -v` to check version)

Comment: Omg, this work perfectly! thanks Kjetil, you're awesome!